# How to Select First or Second or All Options using Asp.Net CheckboxList?

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

The code below checks first `ListItem` (valued 'one') or second (valued 'second') or third (valued 'both'). how this can be achieved using `asp.net c#`?

```
 <asp:CheckBoxList ID="txtoneSecond" runat="server" RepeatColumns="3" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" TextAlign="Right" CssClass="chkList">
       <asp:ListItem Value="one">one</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="second">second</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="both">Both</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:CheckBoxList>



.chkList {

        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }

        .chkList label {
            display: inline-block;
            max-width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
            margin-left: 10px;
        }
```

Comment: Why not use RadioButtons? They only allow one option.

Comment: `<asp:ListItem Value="one" Selected="true">one</asp:ListItem>`

Comment: No not like this.i want to make selected true after i checked.

Comment: You can loop them with this `$('#<%= txtoneSecond.ClientID %> input').each(function (index, element) { //code });` and apply your checked/unchecked logic in there.